# Is it possible to connect to external device via Bluetooth from iPhone. The target device is not an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I want to develop a toy car, which I can use iPhone to control it. My toy car has a bluetooth interface. So I am wondering is it possible to connect to it from my iPhone. The toy car is not a MFi (made for iPhone/iPod/iPad) program.

My iPhone mode is iPhone 4S.

If not possible, is there any alternative way?

Comment: I have just heard that about Core BlueTooth in iOS5.0 can connect to external accessories without MFi. Does it mean that my external accessory should have a BlueTooth LE interface? My toy car has only Bluetooth 2.0 interface right now.

Comment: yes you can use CoreBluetooth to interact with BLE devices, and that would be a perfectly good way to go.  A car remote doesn't need high data rate, so LE is well suited.  But yes, you need the car to have a 4.0 BT device

Comment: Thanks, TJD. It's a greate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without joining Apple's Made for iPhone (MFi) program, your choices are really WiFi or Bluetooth LE. WiFi is more power-hungry and, unless you're very careful in your chip selection, can be difficult to implement. Bluetooth LE is only supported by iPhone 4S and the new iPad (i.e. 3rd-gen); it's likely to be supported in future iOS devices, such as the new iPhone and much-rumoured 'mini' iPad.

Just Bluetooth 4.0 isn't enough, from my understanding, it needs to be Bluetooth 4.0 LE (the low-energy variant). Support for such devices is provided in the iOS 5.0 SDK and later with the `CoreBluetooth` framework. See [Apple's documentation on the `CoreBluetooth` framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295) [free developer registration required].